# PHP mail CC only for the reply all

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to add CC to a PHP email but not send the email to the CC. The CC would only be in place for the reply all on the recipients end. I am thinking something similar to the Reply-to and From Header attributes.

Comment: Try BCC, that way if someone replies they can't reply to the whole list since it is not provided, and then you can set the Reply-To/From field as you want. Not sure if I am understanding your question though.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to generate an email that misrepresents something about how the message was actually sent. Don't lie. Use the Reply-To header (your instinct is right), as in example #2 [on the PHP manpage for mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

**EDIT 1:** To clarify - if an address appears on the Cc line, the recipient will assume that a copy of the message was sent there as well. If your goal is to create a message which gives the appearance of having been sent to an address which did not actually receive a copy (which is certainly possible), then you are misrepresenting the message delivery. I'm recommending that you not do this. Perhaps a bit more detail in the question about what you want to do would help us understand?

**EDIT 2:** Here's an example that shows how to you can advise the email client of your message recipient to reply to a different set of addresses than those which received the original message:

```
<?php
$to = 'you@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$replyList = array(
    'me@example.com',
    'him@acme.com',
    'her@ajax.com'
); 
$headers = array(
    'From: me@example.com',
    'Reply-To: ' . implode(',', $replyList)
);
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Note, however, that there is nothing in [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) which *requires* mail clients to even support distinct "Reply" and "Reply All" operations, so there is no way for you to prepare your email message headers to precisely control the behavior of "Reply" vs. "Reply All".

In particular, there is no standard way to make "Reply" send a message back to the sender only and "Reply All" send a message back to a list of people who were not recipients of the original message. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: This is about putting someone in `Cc` and not putting him in `RCPT TO`, so the person will only be bothered when someone hits "reply all". A totally legit question and the docs you linked don't make a clear statement about the matter.

Comment: @AndreKR - That's your interpretation of the original question ("Is it possible to add CC to a PHP email but not send the email to the CC?"), but by no means obvious. And if you actually bother to read example #2 in the link which I posted you would see how a "Reply-To" header is actually included, demonstrating how this might be done.

Comment: @Peter are you suggesting changing this
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$fromName." <".$from.">\r\n";
     if(strlen($ccEmailAccounts) > 0){
      $headers .= "Cc: ".$ccEmailAccounts."\r\n";
     }
     if(strlen($bccEmailAccounts) > 0){
      $headers .= "Bcc: ".$bccEmailAccounts."\r\n";
     }

to $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$fromName." <".$from.">, ".$cc." <".$CCEmail.">\r\n";

Comment: @ImaginedDesign - I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to do. But if you don't want a copy of the "outbound" message sent to the $ccEmailAccounts address(es) then don't put them in the "Cc:" header. I'll update my answer again with some more details.

Comment: @peter I would like the emails in the cc field but I only want them there for when people hit reply all. This is an automated email and so I don't want to send 100 emails a day to the cc people if not needed.

Comment: @ImaginedDesign - Then use 'Reply-To' and accept that everyone in the list will get a copy of every 'Reply', not just 'Reply All'. The difference between 'Reply' and 'Reply All' that you're looking for isn't supported by any RFCs that I can find, and certainly isn't appropriate for Cc. To get exactly what you're asking for you would need to hack your MTA and effectively tell it to lie to your message recipients, which IMO is a Bad Idea.

Comment: By the way everyone, a downvote with no comment is lame. If you've actually got something useful to say then share it so others can benefit. And *you* might actually learn something if you leave a comment and someone replies to it.